# How could I add NI-VISA (national instrument Virtual Instrument Software Architecture) in my project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visa

My last post was not clear, so I hope I could make my question clearer this time and provide as many as information as possible.

I am trying to write a visual basic program to talk with an electric load (6060B) through GBIP.  I am using visual studio 2013, the target frame that I am using is .NET FRAMEWORK 4.5.  After searching the internet, I decided to use VISA library from National Instrument.
So the problem is how to reference VISA library to my project so I can use the provided functions. I did the research, I understand that I have to link the visa32.dll to my project, but it failed.
I tried to use regsrv32 command to register the visa.dll but it also failed. Then I tried something new that I put the visa32.bas in the project folder so I could use all the function in the visa library; however, it generated a error that complaining about the keyword of "Global".

> E.g. Global Const VI_SPEC_VERSION  = &H00300000&..

the compiler complains about the "Global". How could I solve this?

I think I just run out of idea now.  Any hit or suggestion will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's VB6, which is completely different from VB.Net.  You may need to use COM interop, or port their code to VB.Net.

Comment: Hi SLaks, thank you for response.  To me, it does not matter if I use VB6 and VB.net since I never use both of them, so I am willing to use either one of them.   I just want to pick one so I could use VISA.. So do you know how can I reference the VISA to my project?

Comment: If you want to use the source code in a VB6 project rather than VB.Net, you can't do that with Visual Studio 2013, you will need a copy of VB6 (which was retired about 14 years ago). The alternative is to use COM Interop (as @SLaks says) to use the compiled DLL. Try researching COM Interop for pointers on how to do that.

Comment: The ;larger problem than "Global" is that the whole rest of that file was nothing but PInvoke declarations.  Every one of them will need to be revised if you want to use VB.NET

Comment: Hi Blackwood, thank you for the response. I still want to make sure that I understand what you said.  Do you mean that  I could forget about "VISA library" and focus on COM interop (a library??).   However, COM interop is not a library(based on my understanding), it is a technique that could convert between .NET and COM object.  I assume that in COM interop (I just consider it as a library for now) there is another set of "functions" that do the same as VISA library does, since both of them are basically wrappers of NI-488.2 functions. E.g. ibwrt .Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Hi Plutonix, thank you for your response.  I don't quite sure about Plnvoke declarations.  I just think "global" here as skeleton that I does not do the work?

Comment: I have no idea what your "VISA library is". If its source code contains a statement that begins `Global Const`, then I assume it is not a .Net library. However, if it is a COM library a .Net application can still use the "VISA library" by making use of the Com Interop feature.

Comment: Regarding the [File you posted on your old question](http://www.av.it.pt/medidas/data/Manuais%20&%20Tutoriais/18%20-%20Real%20Time%20Oscilloscope%2020Ghz/CD1/CD1/TekVISA/WinRoot/VXIpnp/WINNT/include/visa32.bas) from a sock puppet account, few of those `Declare` statements are going to be correct for VB.NET.  Look around for a more up to date API

Comment: Thank you Blackwood and Plutonix for the advice.  I guess I have to find the way to add NI-visa to the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of researching, I finally figured it out.
VISA has API in COM, C, .Net. Since I am using .NET Framework 4.5, I have to use VISA.NET API. Now I know the reason why when I wrote ViSession, the compiler complained because ViSession is covered in VISA C rather than VISA.NET. Then the problem left is to add the reference to the project.  Follow the link below, and you will successfully do so.
http://www.ni.com/tutorial/2739/en/
Here I thank everyone who post comments to guide me to the right track..I hope my answer could help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it would seem that your problem is that you are trying to use an old VB6 library in VB.NET. To use VISA from VB.NET, try the following:

- Install NI VISA from the National Instruments [website](https://www.ni.com/visa/) (Click on the Downloads Link on this page, then find a recent version of NI-VISA).
- Get rid of any reference to visa32.dll in your project.
- Add references to Ivi.Visa and NationalInstruments.Visa in your project. These should contain all the commands you need.

Comment: Hi RPM, I followed the instruction.  I added lvi.Visa and Nationalinstruments.Visa in my  project from "add reference" under "assembly".  Then when I typed "Dim stat As ViStatus" in my project,  the compiler still complains about that "ViStatus is not defined".  Did I miss some steps?  Thanks

Comment: I guess my question can narrow down how to add NI-VISA to the reference.  It seems like I have to add NationalInstrumentNS.dll, but I could not locate the place.  I get the idea from the NI forum. Here is the link  http://forums.ni.com/t5/Measurement-Studio-for-NET/Can-t-find-reference-NationalInstruments-visaNS-C/m-p/3015649/highlight/true#M15931